# wordpress sidebar displaying in wrong spot

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I sort of feel like a moron for asking this but I've been stumped on this question for about 2 days. On a website I'm trying to put together, http://gravenimage.us/awf/ , the sidebar, which I want to be on the right in the main content area, is showing up at that bottom. I've tried adjusting the max-width, css align, css display, and a bunch of other things. I've gotten the sidebar to move around a little bit but that's it. I'm pretty sure the issue is that the main content is fixed to a certain width, and it's supposed to be flexible for when the sidebar is called, but that's just not happening. Any ideas? I'd really appreciate some assistance.

http://www.gravenimage.us/awf/screenshot.png

Answer (score 0):

Check your page / post copy... make sure to view HTML mode and not the visual mode, 
check for any rouge opening or closing div tags that may be there,

when you copy paste content into the visual editor, most of the time any html content will be pasted in there also..

or check the theme /page.php file, looks like the sidebar is being pulled in the content div, messing up the rest of the layout!

check for any instance of...

```
<?php the_content();?>
<?php get_sidebar();?>
```

good luck..